# Can no longer create or copy GCE instance templates

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, devops

Since whatever update happened yesterday I can no longer create or copy any instance templates.  When clicking the 'create' button nothing happens - not even an error.

This is preventing us from deploying updates so this is a critical issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I will post my updates regarding this issue on Google groups thread (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/KtBkUkmCfGs/F_Uxq5PUBAAJ) so you can refer to that for more information.